# Hide an element inside a dropdown element of a form

Tags: css, forms

I want to hide one of the dropdown options from a form I'm using. I want to keep the element in the form, as the form is doing some calculations based on user inputs and if I take out the option from the form it breaks the calculation, so I'd just like to hide it from users so it's still in the form but not visible to users.

I have inspected the area on the form and this is the code. I want to hide the word Liverpool.

```
<select class="iphorm-element-select  iphorm_16_25 select2-hidden-accessible" name="iphorm_16_25" id="iphorm_16_25_5e32cecc9b3f6" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                <option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
                                <option value="Shrewsbury">Shrewsbury</option>
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in an environment that supports HTML5, you can use the `hidden` attribute on the option to hide it.

Note that in order for that to work, it can't be the first `option` (otherwise it will default to that one).

See this working snippet:

```html
<select class="iphorm-element-select  iphorm_16_25 select2-hidden-accessible" name="iphorm_16_25" id="iphorm_16_25_5e32cecc9b3f6" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="-">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Liverpool" hidden>Liverpool</option>
  <option value="Shrewsbury">Shrewsbury</option>
</select>
```

**Following OP Comment About Editing Existing HTML**

OP has stated:

> The issue I will probably face is that the html is generated by a
>   plugin that creates the form, so I can't add that attribute. I was
>   hoping to add a css rule to stop it displaying

Given this circumstance, the CSS property `visibility` could be used to control whether the `option` is visible, as per the following snippet:

```css
select > option:nth-of-type(2) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<select class="iphorm-element-select  iphorm_16_25 select2-hidden-accessible" name="iphorm_16_25" id="iphorm_16_25_5e32cecc9b3f6" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="-">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
  <option value="Shrewsbury">Shrewsbury</option>
</select>
```

However, this has the unfortunate side-effect of leaving a hole in the `select` list as opposed to hiding it completely.  It does, however, prevent that option from being displayed or chosen.

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue I will probably face is that the html is generated by a plugin that creates the form, so I can't add that attribute. I was hoping to add a css rule to stop it displaying

Comment: @kendavies You're welcome. In the case of existing HTML you can't modify, see my edit which includes a CSS-based method for hiding the `option`.